# I am trying to find a specific object in an array using node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, json

My array is:

```
[
    {
        "_attributes": {
            "key": "attributes"
        },
        "dt_assoc": {
            "item": {
                "_attributes": {
                    "key": "status"
                },
                "_text": "taken"
            }
        }
    }
]
```

I have tried a couple of options but can't seem to get a specific object. Im trying to get; "dt_assoc":

```
{
            "item": {
                "_attributes": {
                    "key": "status"
                },
                "_text": "taken"
            };
```

Answer (score 1):

That's an array with only one item. Counting starts at zero. So to get to the item, you'd use `array[0]`.

That will get you the object. That object has a property named `dt_assoc`. To access the property, you'd use `array[0].dt_assoc`.

Answer (score 0):

You access it by specifying index as 0 because it is an array.

```js
const data = [{
  "_attributes": {
    "key": "attributes"
  },
  "dt_assoc": {
    "item": {
      "_attributes": {
        "key": "status"
      },
      "_text": "taken"
    }
  }
}]
console.log(data[0].dt_assoc)
```